# Checkbox Column in the Datagridview toggles in Virtual Mode

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a `Datagridview` in Virtual Mode. One of the columns in the `Datagridview` is a checkbox column.

So, When I click on the checkbox in any row, the checked value toggles in the other rows. I am not able to select multiple entries.

So, if I checked Row 2, and when Row 3 is also checked, the row 2 would automatically uncheck.

Any idea if I have missed anything.

Thanks

Comment: How are you handling the Value needed events ?

Comment: Hi, Regarding CellValueNeeded() event handler. Currently I am not handling it for this column( the checkbox column).